# Function PropertyAccessor.DeleteProperties not working in Outlook 2016?

Tags: c#, outlook, outlook-addin

I have an Outlook COM add-in (C#, Visual Studio 2012) that extends the standard form with additional message properties. The add-in works with Outlook 2010, 2013 and 2016.

Ideally I would put these properties on a form region, but as the properties need to be in namespace PS_INTERNET_HEADERS, and that is not possible with a form region. Instead I have a custom task pane with controls for all my properties. To get in sync with the Outlook flow for saving messages, I still have a form region, that is hidden and contains a single internal property in namespace PS_PUBLIC_STRINGS. Whenever one of my properties in the custom task pane changes, I change the value of this internal property. I then listen to MailItem.CustomPropertyChanged and when that event occurs for the internal property, I use PropertyAccessor.SetProperties to set the properties in namespace PS_INTERNET_HEADERS; if a property is empty, I use PropertyAccessor.DeleteProperties, since there is a semantic difference of a property having an empty value or not being present at all.

In addition to all this, I listen to Application.ItemSend, where I check all the properties for having valid values; if not, the send is cancelled.

That works fine most of the time. But the problem is that it fails on Outlook 2016 for a specific scenario. The scenario is:

- Create a message, fill in receiver, subject, body and set one of the PS_INTERNET_HEADERS properties controls to an invalid value.
- Try send; the send is cancelled via Application.ItemSend, since a property has an invalid value.
- Delete the invalid value and send the message.

Now the sent item still and erroneously has the invalid value, it ought not be there at all, since I called PropertyAccessor.DeleteProperties. For debugging, in the Application.ItemSend handler I call PropertyAccessor.GetProperties and the property is actually gone! If instead of deleting the property, I set the property to an empty string, it works - but as I said that's not sufficient. I can only provoke this error if the send is cancelled at least once in the Application.ItemSend handler.

My workaround for this is to call MailItem.Save after all the calls to PropertyAccessor.SetProperties and PropertyAccessor.DeleteProperties. That however creates a draft mail item, which I would like to avoid.

Any clue of what I can do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved the problem (left out the code to release COM object rdoMail):

```
    private static void DeleteHeader(Redemption.RDOSession rdoSession, Outlook.MailItem mailItem, string name)
    {
        const int MapiPropertyTypeUnicodeString = 31;
        var rdoMail = (Redemption.RDOMail)rdoSession.GetRDOObjectFromOutlookObject(mailItem);
        var tag = rdoMail.GetIDsFromNames("{00020386-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}", name) | MapiPropertyTypeUnicodeString;
        rdoMail.Fields[tag] = null;
    }
```